# Entity Framework Core: Check if an entity part of a One-to-Many relationship exists on Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I am very new to Entity Framework Core (Entity Framework in General), and I have watched several tutorial videos and done a Pluralsight course.

I am using ASP.NET Web API, and I want to add a new entity, that has a One-to-Many relationship. The models are as follows:

---

"Parent" Class:

```
public partial class VerificationVoltage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int VerificationVoltageSerialId { get; set; }

    public VerificationVoltageSerial Serial { get; set; }
}
```

---

"Child" Class:

```
public class VerificationVoltageSerial
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
        
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Serial { get; set; }

    public List<VerificationVoltage> VerificationVoltage { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the `VerificationVoltageSerial.Serial` to be unique, and that the database will first check whether or not the serial exists, before adding the newly added serial (The serials themselves are unique).

Is there a way to do the following: If a row with the same serial exist, as what needs to be added, entity framework then automatically selects the Serial and SerialId and populates the Entity that is being added, with the serial selected from the database.

This is what I am doing currently, I feel that this is a very manual check, an maybe there is something more automatic: (i.e I want it to wrok, even if I remove the IF Statement and the exisitngEntry query in the controller)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<VerificationVoltage> AddVerificationVoltage(VerificationVoltage verificationVoltage)
{
    var exisitngEntry = await repository.GetBySerialNoTracking(verificationVoltage.Serial.Serial)
                                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (exisitngEntry != null)
    {
        var existingSerial = exisitngEntry.Serial;
        verificationVoltage.Serial.Id = existingSerial.Id;
        verificationVoltage.Serial = new VerificationVoltageSerial()
        {
            Id = existingSerial.Id,
            Serial = existingSerial.Serial,
        };
    }

    var addedEntry = repository.Add(verificationVoltage); 
    await repository.SaveChanges().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return addedEntry;
}
```

```
public async Task<VerificationVoltage> GetBySerialNoTracking(string serialNumber)
{
    return await DbSet.Include(a => a.Serial)
                      .Where(a => a.Serial.Serial.Equals(serialNumber))
                      .OrderBy(a => a.VerificationVoltageSerialId)
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

My `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, only repeats the attributes:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ValidationLabAmbientMeasurements>()
                .HasOne(a => a.AmbientMeasurementsIdentifier)
                .WithMany();

    modelBuilder.Entity<VerificationVoltage>()
                .Property(a => a.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    modelBuilder.Entity<VerificationVoltage>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Serial)
                .WithMany(nameof(VerificationVoltage));

    modelBuilder.Entity<VerificationVoltage>()
                .HasMany(a => a.VerificationVoltageMeasurements)
                .WithOne(nameof(VerificationVoltage));
}
```

I have tried searching for answers, but my search queries do not get results on this specific issue.

Comment: Is there any reason to do not write this directly? verificationVoltage.Serial = exisitngEntry.Serial

Comment: And I think you should not use Attach. Instead, use Add or Update

Comment: I can add it directly I however want to know if it is possible to do this without having to query the database manually to see if this Serial exists. Also, add in this case seems to work the same as Attach (I will change the code to reflect the add method)

Comment: As far as I know, you need to check if it exists, since you do not know the Id.